# Where can I find reliable place to find specifications about my car?

Tags: toyota, automatic-transmission, fuel-tank, cvt-transmission

I have a Toyota Corolla (Fielder - 1ZZ-FE).

I'm struggling to find a place where I can find detailed specifications about other parts. For example,  I would like to know the transmission type (CVT or common AT), tank volume, and some other stuff.

The owners manual is extremely scarce and has only superficial info...

Comment: Some, or most, manufacturers have a VIN decoder - gives full detail of the build spec... trim level, tire & wheel size, paint code, engine, radio spec, parking sensors etc. Got it for my car, and kept the detail...

Comment: [Try this Toyota site](https://www.toyota.com/owners/my-vehicle/vehicle-specification) punch in your vin code

Comment: @SolarMike, thanks for the tip. I tried to look upon Toyota's website, but my VIN shows as invalid. I'm sure that car if fine (legal). Seems a bit strange.